# AWS STS Temporary Credentials S3 Access Denied PutObject

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sts

I am following the [How to Use AWS IAM with STS for access to AWS resources - 2nd Watch](https://www.2ndwatch.com/blog/use-aws-iam-sts-access-aws-resources/) blog post and my understanding is the S3 Bucket Policy Principal requesting the temporary credentials, one approach would be to hard code the Id of this User but the post attempts a more elegant approach of evaluating the STS delegated user (when it works).

arn:aws:iam::409812999999999999:policy/fts-assume-role

IAM user policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

arn:aws:s3:::finding-taylor-swift

s3 bucket policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1581282599999999999",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt158128999999999999",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "sts.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::finding-taylor-swift/*"
        }
    ]
}


conor@xyz:~$ aws configure --profile finding-taylor-swift
AWS Access Key ID [****************6QNY]: 
AWS Secret Access Key [****************+8kF]: 
Default region name [eu-west-2]: 
Default output format [text]: json
conor@xyz:~$ aws sts get-session-token --profile finding-taylor-swift
{
    "Credentials": {
        "SecretAccessKey": "<some text>", 
        "SessionToken": "<some text>", 
        "Expiration": "2020-02-11T03:31:50Z", 
        "AccessKeyId": "<some text>"
    }
}
conor@xyz:~$ export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=<some text>
conor@xyz:~$ export AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=<some text>
conor@xyz:~$ export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=<some text>
conor@xyz:~$ aws s3 cp dreamstime_xxl_concert_profile_w500_q8.jpg s3://finding-taylor-swift
upload failed: ./dreamstime_xxl_concert_profile_w500_q8.jpg to s3://finding-taylor-swift/dreamstime_xxl_concert_profile_w500_q8.jpg An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied
conor@xyz:~$
```

AWS CLI has been setup as described on [Using Temporary Security Credentials with the AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_temp_use-resources.html#using-temp-creds-sdk-cli)

"When you run AWS CLI commands, the AWS CLI looks for credentials in a specific order—first in environment variables and then in the configuration file. Therefore, after you've put the temporary credentials into environment variables, the AWS CLI uses those credentials by default. (If you specify a profile parameter in the command, the AWS CLI skips the environment variables. Instead, the AWS CLI looks in the configuration file, which lets you override the credentials in the environment variables if you need to.)

The following example shows how you might set the environment variables for temporary security credentials and then call an AWS CLI command. Because no profile parameter is included in the AWS CLI command, the AWS CLI looks for credentials first in environment variables and therefore uses the temporary credentials."

Comment: 2 things come to mind, 1 arns have form <aws:service:acct-id:other-stuff> if the 4.............. above is a valid account id its not a good idea to expose it. 2 have you set up the profile for aws cli to use the sts credentials correctly as shown here ? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-role.html

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @NigelSavage but account ids are not real, I believe the aws cli is using the shell environment variables in the first instance described here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_temp_use-resources.html#using-temp-creds-sdk-cli
I don't want to use the profile 'finding-taylor-swift' as this is then not using the STS temporary credentials

Comment: maybe try assume role https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sts/assume-role.html That was the point i was trying to make before.

Comment: "The temporary security credentials created by AssumeRole can be used to make API calls to any AWS service with the following exception: You cannot call the AWS STS GetFederationToken or GetSessionToken API operations."

"For AWS CLI use, you can set up a named profile associated with a role. When you use the profile, the AWS CLI will call assume-role and manage credentials for you. See Assuming a Role in the AWS CLI User Guide for instructions."

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sts/assume-role.html

my feel is the s3 policy is the issue @NigelSavage

Comment: @Conor What is your specific use-case here? It is quite unusual to use `GetSessionToken`. Using an IAM Role is much more common. Can you tell us more about what you specifically wish to accomplish? That way, we can provide an appropriate answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to use a **Bucket Policy** for your scenario. A bucket policy is applied to an Amazon S3 bucket and is typically used to grant access that is specific to the bucket (eg public access).

**Using an IAM Role**

If you wish to provide bucket access to a specific IAM User, IAM Group or IAM Role, then the permissions should be attached to the IAM entity rather than the bucket.

(For `get-session-token`, see the end of my answer.)

**Setup**

Let's start by creating an IAM Role similar to what you had. I choose **Create role**, then for trusted entity I select **Another AWS account** (since it will be assumed by an IAM User rather than service).

I then create an **Inline policy** on the IAM Role to permit access to the bucket:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket"
        }
    ]
}
```

(It's normally not a good idea to assign `s3:*` permissions, since this lets the user delete content and even delete the bucket. Try to restrict it to the minimum permissions that are actually required.)

The **Trust Relationship** on the IAM Role determines who is allowed to *assume* the role. It could be one person, or anyone in the account (as long as they have been granted permission to call `AssumeRole`). In my case, I'll assign it to the whole account:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::MY-ACCOUNT-ID:root"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

Now there are a few different ways to assume the role...

**Simple method: IAM Role in credentials file**

The AWS CLI has the ability to specify an IAM Role in the credentials file, and it will automatically assume the role for you.

See: [Using an IAM Role in the AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-role.html)

To use this, I add a section to my `.aws/config` file:

```
[profile foo]
role_arn = arn:aws:iam::MY-ACCOUNT-ID:role/MY-ROLE-NAME
source_profile = default
```

I could then simply use it with:

```
aws s3 ls s3://my-bucket --profile foo
```

This successfully lets me access that specific bucket.

**Complex method: Assume the role myself**

Rather than letting the AWS CLI do all the work, I can also assume the role myself:

```
aws sts assume-role --role-arn arn:aws:iam::MY-ACCOUNT-ID:role/MY-ROLE-NAME --role-session-name foo

{
    "Credentials": {
        "AccessKeyId": "ASIA...",
        "SecretAccessKey": "...",
        "SessionToken": "...",
        "Expiration": "2020-02-11T00:43:30+00:00"
    },
    "AssumedRoleUser": {
        "AssumedRoleId": "AROA...:foo",
        "Arn": "arn:aws:sts::MY-ACCOUNT-ID:assumed-role/MY-ROLE-NAME/foo"
    }
}
```

I then appended this information to the `.aws/credentials` file:

```
[foo2]
aws_access_key_id = ASIA...
aws_secret_access_key = ...
aws_security_token= ...
```

Yes, you could add this to the credentials file by using `aws configure --foo2`, but it does not prompt for the Security Token. Therefore, you need to edit the credentials file to add that information anyway.

I then used the profile:

```
aws s3 ls s3://my-bucket --profile foo2
```

It allowed me to successfully access and use the bucket.

**Using GetSessionToken**

The above examples use an **IAM Role**. This is typically used to grant cross-account access or to temporarily assume more-powerful credentials (eg an Admin performing sensitive operations).

Your Question references [`get-session-token`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_GetSessionToken.html). This provides **temporary credentials based on a user's existing credentials and permissions**. Thus, they cannot gain additional permissions as part of this API call.

This call is typically used either to supply an MFA token or to provide time-limited credentials for testing purposes. For example, I could give you credentials that effectively let you use my IAM User, but only for a limited time.